# Firebug: How do I get only the list console.log() items in the console tab?

Tags: firefox, webkit, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

During debugging, I feel sometime to see only the console.log() stuffs in the **Console** tab of the developer tools. How do I achieve this? What settings or configuration will help me to achieve this if it all this is a possible way in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option (also no hidden one) to only display `console.log()` output in Firebug (as of version 2.0.x).

The only filters it offers are shown within the panel toolbar and those are for errors (like `console.error()`), warnings (like `console.warn()`), info messages (like `console.info()`) and debugging messages (like `console.debug()`) and cookies.